# Dúvida com scanner

Tags: java

Queria uma ajuda com um programa que perguntaria pra pessoa de qual cidade ela é. Se ela digitar uma cidade diferente da programada, o programa diria que a pessoa não poderia prosseguir (pretendo usar If pra isso).

```
Scanner teste = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Digite sua cidade: ");
```

Depois disso, eu teria que criar uma variável chamada cidadedigitada, e posteriormente o IF cidadedigitada for diferente da cidade programada,o usuário não poderá prosseguir.

O problema é que não sei qual variável primitiva usar para o cidadedigitada (se fosse um número,eu poderia usar int ou double,por exemplo,mas como se trata de um texto,não sei qual variável usar).

Comment: Por que nao string? Se utilizar numeros, precisará mapea-los as cidades para poder conseguir relaciona-los. Melhor fazer direto com strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa-se um tipo de dado que não é primitivo, chamado `String`.

Atenção que para comparar duas Strings não se usa o `==` e sim o `equals()`. Exemplo:

```
if (stringDigitada.equals("São Paulo")) {
    ...
}
```

Você deveria procurar um tutorial sobre Java. Ou pensando melhor, eu não sei por que você está aprendendo programação básica com Java, se é matéria da faculdade ou algo do tipo. Acho que seria melhor começar com uma linguagem estruturada e não uma linguagem orientada a objetos. Java é orientada a objetos, o que deixa as coisas mais complicadas, por exemplo uma `String` é um objeto, que é um tipo de dado que possui funções agregadas a ele (note no exemplo acima que o objeto `stringDigitada` possui uma função `equals()` agregada a ele, que está sendo chamada assim: `stringDigitada.equals(...)`). Essas funções são chamadas "métodos".

Se quer aprender programação e não tem um motivo especial para usar Java, eu sugiro que primeiramente escolha uma linguagem com suporte a programação estruturada como Python ou C e que em seguida procure um material de aprendizado adequado para te orientar nesse caminho, que pode ser um tutorial, livro ou vídeo-aulas. Talvez antes mesmo de fazer isso procure material para aprender sobre uma coisa chamada "lógica de programação", que provavelmente será ensinada em alguma pseudolinguagem como Portugol (embora seja possível encontrar material sobre lógica de programação já na linguagem de programação desejada).

Espero que essas orientações possam ser úteis.

Comment: Não tenho um motivo especial pra aprender, sou simplismente um autodidata.Talvez me identifique na área e leve isso pra minha vida, considerando que sou bem novo. Fiz um curso de excel avançado e foi meu primeiro contato com a programação,gostei e to tentando me aprofundar simplismente por interesse.Aliás,estou aprendendo através de algumas videoaulas de um cara chamado "Lucas Iório" no youtube. Ele publicou um curso de "Java para iniciantes".Na aula 5, ele fala sobre scanners, mas a impossibilidade de fazer o que eu queria me bateu a dúvida e vim aqui perguntar

Comment: Que bom, espero que goste. Isso que falei na resposta é o "caminho das pedras" para tentar facilitar seu aprendizado e assim você se interessar mais, embora a área tenha muitos desafios, mas são desafios gostosos de resolver. Espero que possa ser útil.

Comment: Dei uma olhada aqui, o "professor" só fala sobre as "strings" na aula 9...Considerando que estou na 5, ainda tenho um bom caminho pela frente, mas não pretendo pular as aulas,baby steps...

Comment: Ok. Se achar que a resposta atendeu sua dúvida, não esqueça de aceitá-la clicando no ✅ no canto superior esquerdo da mesma.